# How to create proxy server for wcf service

Tags: wcf, service, proxy, server

I have to connect to a WCF service that resides on a internal server (lets say its name is A). The network administrator does not allow me to access the server A directly. He wants me to use another server (B) in his network as a proxy server. He tells me to create some kind of software that will be published on server B so that I will be communicating directly only to server B which will be able to access server A and pass the response to me. Is there a simple method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what kind of authentication is used to connect to the service and what type of access restrictions or controls are in place between server A and server B. For example, is server A in a protected cage environment under PCI controls and/or a different AD domain? The solution could be a basic port forwarding/tunneling setup, or you may end up having to set up a new WCF service on B, switch authentication models, etc.

Comment: Thank you. At the moment I have not been provided with many details. I have to assume that authentication models will be different and a new WCF service was what I was thinking about. I think this solution will be the most flexible - when requirements change I will need only reconfigure the proxy service. I need to create the proxy WCF service with the least code possible - ideally with no code, being able to tune it only with configuration.

Comment: That's a sound option, and my advice would be to understand the key concerns that were raised by the network admin so that your solution will be tailored to address them. Quite often I've seen situations where the solution implemented as a runaround for a restriction ended up creating a bigger security problem.